# Vim not reading/loading Ctags files on Mac

Tags: macos, vim, ctags, command-line-interface

Ok this should be a lot easier than it is and I am pulling my hair out trying to figure it out. I've watched other tutorials and everyone else's works just fine but it just doesn't work for me. I've got OSX 10.9.2, Ctags 5.8 and vim 7.3. I got into a directory and run

```
ctags -R .
```

A tags file is created. I can open the tags file up and there are definitions in there that correspond to the tags that I want so sweet I got tags so I load vim in the same directory as my tags file and use

```
:tags
```

and nothing shows up. I've also tried setting the tags with

```
:set tags=./tags;tags
```

and still I get nothing in my tag stack. What am I missing? do I have to change some kind of environment variables? I don't understand why I can't just read the tags file that was created. This is driving me nuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing two important details:

- the tagstack is updated each time you jump to and from a tag, which you didn't;
- the `:tags` command allows you to visualize the tagstack, which is empty.

To jump to tag `foo`, do:

```
:tag foo
```

To jump to a tag that contains `foo`, do:

```
:tag /foo<tab>
```

And read `:help tags` more carefully.

Comment: Thank you for the quick tip I definitely was hasty in my excitement to start using tags. I appreciate your quick tip.

Comment: i am also having the same issue. but when i do a `Ctrl-]` on a symbol, vim say no tag file found